# What's this computer in the 1988 movie "Vampire's Kiss"?

Tags: identify-this-computer, 80186

This is a grab from a 1988 movie called Vampire's Kiss.

It has twin disk drives (5.25" from the looks) and what looks like a built-in printer?

[image: still of movie]

Comment: @njuffa It could be a workstation built for a particular profession, e.g. a lawyer's office, but as you say, we need more context.

Comment: I think there are two units on the desk, butted up against each other.

Comment: I'm guessing it's a dedicated word processing system, rather than a generic computer.

Comment: There seems to be a manufacturer's logo on the front of the printer, but we need to see a close-up to make it out.

Comment: It looks surprisingly similar (but not quite like) to Toshiba's 1982 *TOSWORD* desktop word processing system (https://etzone.org/2018/06/12/tosword/)

Comment: How well can you actually read a 12" screen from like 4 feet away? That desk was definitely arranged by Hollywood.

Comment: @640KB You actually can - the machine has an excellent amber text screen which is super-sharp.

Comment: This kind of question is usually answered on starringthecomputer.com.  But apparently it's only in this list so far: http://www.starringthecomputer.com/movies.txt

Comment: @640KB Those monochrome monitors are also very low resolution by modern standards, about 720x350 (Yeah, they weren't square pixels).  And with only 2 colors, amber/green/blue/white and black (this one appears to be amber), it's not at all hard to read from a distance.

Comment: @640KB With binoculars!?  In the 1980s, I worked on a remote sensing satellite system.  "Control points" were distinctive points on the ground with known locations; small images (aerial photographs?) of control points could be registered to similar objects in the satellite imagery to provide more accurate geometric correction.  Quality maps were put on a large digitizer board so as to precisely determine control point locations.  Doug aligned/tuned the digitizer, but his VT100 terminal was about 30 feet away, so he used a pair of binoculars to see what coordinates the digitizer was reporting!

Comment: @640KB has a point though. The ergonomics of that work station are appalling, and it's not just the placement of the monitor. Look at how she's reaching _up_ to the keyboard, and how the keyboard is so close, it's practically touching her solar plexus.

Comment: Screens were typically 80x25 or 40x25 text, quite readable from that distance even on a 12" ...

Answer (score 82, accepted):

That's a [Minolta PCW1 Word processor](https://collection.cooperhewitt.org/objects/18648469/) of Minolta Camera Co. Ltd

The "computer part" is in fact a PC with 512kBytes memory and a 80186 CPU running DOS 2.11 and proprietary word processing (or, rather: typewriter emulation) software written by a company named Carlisle Systems. The printer part apparently is a NEC daisy-wheel OEM module. The two modules came separately and can/must be bolted together.

It's relatively rare, as apparently only 10.000 units have been built.

Comment: It's super beautiful.

Comment: IIRC MSDOS needed to be a special version to run on 80186 machines, since they were never truly IBM PC compatible due to the 80186 having built in peripherals that conflicted with the IBM PC memory map standard.

Comment: @rackandboneman Probably not a spacific DOS version, but certainly a specific BIOS to handle the on-board timer, interrupt and DMA controllers. DOS doesn't do much with them, but still, the Minolta DOS for the PCW1 apparently was a proprietary version.

Comment: It's made for exactly one function and I have to assume it fulfils it nicely.

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche I agree! My first thought was that looks like a Mac SE and an ImageWriter mashed together, they have that same aesthetic. Perhaps it's an ultrawide edition of the Lisa ? ;-)

Comment: "10.000 units" .. guessing you mean ten *thousand*?

Comment: @boann Yes - a European number ;)

Comment: @tofro The thousands separator in English is a comma.

Comment: @Boann - no, the mistake is that it should be in kilounits...

Comment: @JonCuster If it were in kilounits I'd doubt the number of significant digits there...

Comment: @called2voyage - sure, but 10.0000 kilounits would be even more in doubt... Tongue was firmly in cheek, that doesn't come across well in comments...

Comment: @JonCuster Oh, I got it, I was just playing along, lol.

Comment: This dedicated word processor would have been beautiful on my desk, as I typed with the wonderful sounds coming from my [BeoCenter 9000](https://www.beoworld.org/prod_details.asp?pid=410) on the cabinet next to me.